# Adding HTTP Basic Authentication to some routes in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

I want to add HTTP Basic Authentication to a some of my routes in my `routes.rb` file.

I got the idea from http://asciicasts.com/episodes/271-resque

`routes.rb`

```
Coderbits::Application.routes.draw do  
  resources :snippets  
  root :to => "snippets#new"  
  authenticate :admin do  
    mount Resque::Server, :at => "/resque"  
  end  
end
```

`config/initializers/resque_auth.rb`

```
Resque::Server.use(Rack::Auth::Basic) do |user, password|  
  password == "secret"  
end
```

If I just want to protect routes that are in my rails app, what should I put in the initializer file?

My work around for right now is to add a before filter in my application controller using if the request is not for a controller that I've whitelisted:

```
authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |user, password|
  user == ENV["ADMIN_USER"] && password == ENV["ADMIN_PASS"]
end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just put

```
  http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "admin", :password => "secret"
```

inside my controller

Comment: Thanks - perfect solution! Works also in Rails 5.